# disabling access to weaker WiFi signals

Tags: wireless

I installed a WiFi repeater.  With it I get a 4 bar signal.  Without it I get 2 bars.  From time to time, my system will switch to the original 2 bar signal.  How can I disable access to the original weak signal?

I am on 10.10 (Maverick).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the ubuntu menu bar, right click the signal strength icon.  Select `Edit Connections`.  Select the `wireless` tab.  Even if you do not know the name of the original wireless connection, delete all but the one that you want to use.